# How to send some specific module to another page after login laravel

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-4

Can any one help me I have to redirect search module after login to search listing page else when user will login will go to home page how i will achieve it.
routes.php is below:

```
    Route::group(array('before' => ['auth' ,'temp-actions']), function(){
Route::get('doc_search',
            array(
                'as' => 'search',
                'uses' => 'App\Modules\Core\Controllers\SearchController@index'
            )
        );
}
});
```

Please please help me out

Answer (score 0):

Add redirectTo property on your AuthController

```
protected $redirectTo = 'route/to/search';
```

After logging in, they will be redirected to that route automatically

Comment: Thanks for reply jen but I want only for search module which will redirect to search only others will redirect to home page itself

Comment: what are your bases for that others? user groups? then check for it's user groups first then redirect them using the authorized method. Authorized method is triggered right after a successful login. Check from there then redirect them

Comment: No user group just redirecting to home after successfully login

Comment: Can you please be clear, what is it that you want to redirect to search module? Please be EXACT

Comment: Basically Jen There is many modules in the system in which all will redirect to home page but now the search module which is showing in home page before login when user will search then as per auth login window is appearing now i want when user will login after search it will redirect to search listing after login not in home page

Comment: Add middleware on your search module then also make exception on which method you don't want to authentication.. look at the Authenticate middleware for an example. Or just check it before doing search on the method itself that does it and redirect them to the login page and then after that continue the search method.